# How to remove all roles from user in ASP.NET Identity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use the code below, but get an exception that parameter "manager" is null. How can I fix it?

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task DeleteUserRoles()
    {
        var userId = "ec6ea171-70f5-4fd9-93f2-5a05a2f88e3b";

        await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(userId, _userManager.GetRoles(userId).ToArray());

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that works.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

.......
 private ApplicationUserManager _userManager; 

        public UsersController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;

        }
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
               return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
 [HttpDelete]
        public async Task DeleteUserRoles()
        {
            var userId = "ec6ea171-70f5-4fd9-93f2-5a05a2f88e3b";
            await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(userId, UserManager.GetRoles(userId).ToArray());
        }
```